# 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' followed by 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I always get this 2 errors when executing a query

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
```

Followed by

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

This is how I execute my query

```
Sub Get_Teller_Num(hardware_Add As String)

    Check_DB_Con() 'Check if the connection is okay
    SQL_Query = "SELECT teller_info.teller_num, service_info.service_num " _
        & "FROM service_info " _
        & "JOIN teller_info " _
        & "ON service_info.service_id = teller_info.teller_id " _
        & "WHERE teller_info.hardware_add = " & hardware_Add
    Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(SQL_Query, MysqlConn)

    Try
        MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
        MySQL_Reader = MySQL_CMD.ExecuteReader()

        While MySQL_Reader.Read
            teller_Num = MySQL_Reader("teller_info.teller_num")
            service_Num = MySQL_Reader("service_info.service_num")
        End While
        MySQL_Reader.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to run query: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

As you can see, I am joining another table so I can get certain values to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by adding `ALIAS or AS` in my `WHERE` clause and `reading it based on it` solves the problem.

So instead of this query:

```
SQL_Query = "SELECT teller_info.teller_num, service_info.service_num " _
        & "FROM service_info " _
        & "JOIN teller_info " _
        & "ON service_info.service_id = teller_info.teller_id " _
        & "WHERE teller_info.hardware_add = " & hardware_Add
```

Change it to **`(Notice that I create an ALIAS for the fields that I want to get)`**:

```
 SQL_Query = "SELECT teller_info.teller_num AS Teller_Num, service_info.service_num AS Service_Num " _
        & "FROM service_info " _
        & "JOIN teller_info " _
        & "ON service_info.service_id = teller_info.teller_id " _
        & "WHERE teller_info.hardware_add = " & hardware_Add
```

Then, we also need to change the way we read data.

Instead of this:

```
While MySQL_Reader.Read
    teller_Num = MySQL_Reader("teller_info.teller_num")
    service_Num = MySQL_Reader("service_info.service_num")
End While
```

Change it to **`(Notice that I read them based on the ALIAS that I've given to them)`**:

```
While MySQL_Reader.Read
    teller_Num = MySQL_Reader("Teller_Num")
    service_Num = MySQL_Reader("Service_Num")
End While
```